# Word meaning "to convert into a numerical form"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, numbers

Let's say that one possesses some data or information that one wishes to map to some kind of numerical representation. I can't seem to come up with a word or phrase that describes it well.

As an example, it could be used when converting something like a date string (`"2014-01-02"`) to a UNIX timestamp (`1388620800`).

Generally, I would imagine such a word would be used when the data has some kind of *inherent ordering*, but perhaps isn't directly usable with other numbers. I thought of "quantize", but this seems to imply that the data is somehow discrete, i.e. not continuous, which would (arguably) be inaccurate when referring to time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use  [numericize](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/numericize)  or digitize

and though it does not imply numeric conversion, you may also use **transform**

Comment: Be careful with numericize-- it does not appear to be in Merriam Webster, so it may not be accepted as a real English word yet. Personally, I have never heard or read it before-- but I kind of like it!

Answer (score 2):

The term "parse" comes to mind, mostly because that's what it's called in computer science. You might also be looking for something like "enumerate" or "format"?

Comment: I was hoping for a word that would carry the idea of "transforming to a numeric form _for the purpose of numerical operations_". "Parse" doesn't imply anything about what you plan to do _after_ parsing. "Numericize" (as little-used as it may be) seems to carry the idea better.

Answer (score 0):

The technical term is ["typecasting" or "type conversion"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion)